# C structure padding problems

Tags: c, struct, padding

```
struct something {
    uint32_t a;
    uint8_t  b;
    uint16_t c;
    uint32_t x;
    uint16_t y;
    uint8_t  z;
};

uint8_t *data = malloc(14);
struct something *s = (struct something *)data;

s->a = 1;
s->b = 2;
s->c = 3;
s->x = 4;
s->y = 5;
s->z = 6;
```

Is it always safe to do this in C or structure padding may cause problems?

**Edit 1 (make it clear):** is it guaranteed that data[0]..data[3]==1, data[4]==2, data[5]..data[6]==3, data[7]..data[10]==4, data[11]..data[12]==5 and data[13]==6?

**Edit 2:** little mistake on edit 1

Comment: Did you check the `sizeof` this `struct`ure?

Comment: No it's not safe. Padding *will* be a problem.

Comment: Comment after your edit: No it isn't because of possible padding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is *not* a safe operation.  The compiler will add padding in an implementation defined manner.

Generally speaking, a member of a given size will be aligned on an offset that is a multiple of that size.

Given the typical way padding is done, this `struct` will most likely be 16 bytes in size.  The physical layout will most likely (but not necessarily) look like this:

```
struct something {
    uint32_t a;         // offset 0
    uint8_t  b;         // offset 4
                        // 1 byte padding
    uint16_t c;         // offset 6
    uint32_t x;         // offset 8
    uint16_t y;         // offset 12
    uint8_t  z;         // offset 14
    // 1 byte padding
};
```

Don't use magic numbers.  Intead, use the `sizeof` operator.

```
struct something *s = malloc(sizeof(struct something));
```

EDIT:

If you want to increase the chances that your `struct` is laid out a particular way, see this [guide to structure packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/).  If you follow the practices here, there's a good chance (but not 100%) that your `struct` will be laid out in memory the way you expect.

For gcc, you can use `__attribute__((packed))` on a `struct` to remove padding from a `struct`.  Doing so however may incur a performance penalty or could cause a page fault.  The `-Wpadded` and `-Wpacked` options can also tell you more regarding padding.

Comment: But, if having this ordering and eliminating padding is a **requirement**, your compiler _may_ have tools to help you (but you pay a portability penalty and probably a performance penalty).

Comment: Will these offsets reflect on data stored in the 'data' variable? I edit the question to make it clear. I mean, is the compiler intelligent enough to bypass the problems caused by padding?

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida, no problems are caused by padding unless you do something that depends explicitly on the location or amount of padding.  It is uncommon to need to do such a thing.  No program that does so conforms strictly to the standard.  Depending on an assumption about the offset of the storage a structure member other than the first relative to the start of the structure, such as you ask about in your edit, is exactly such a non-conforming thing.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thats the question, my example depends on the location or amount of padding?

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida, yes, because that affects the location of members' representations within the overall structure's representation.

Comment: @JohnBollinger whats the best way to put data in the 'data' variable following the format of the structure then?

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida, the way you put data in, via pointer `s`, is just fine.  The problem is the assumptions you make about how the members are laid out within.

Comment: @JohnBollinger but its not fine since when doing that the data will not be in the format of the structure, right? there will be padding.

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida, you are not getting it.  Padding chosen by the compiler is ***part of the format*** of the structure.  If you write members via an lvalue of type `struct something`, as you do in your code when you write via pointer `s` of type `struct something *`, you necessarily write in the format of the structure.

Comment: @JohnBollinger No, I see this. What I mean by 'format of the structure' is what I declared, without padding. Like, if I would like to transfer 'data' in a socket, it would come to destination with the padding, right? So, how can I put data in 'data' following the structure format I declared?

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida, in a strictly-conforming program, if you want to perform manual data layout then your options for moving data in and out are few.  `memcpy()` is probably the best of them.  As you back off from *strict* compliance you have other options, such as pointer aliasing tricks and relying on implementation extensions to control structure packing.  dbush has added some comments about the latter alternative.

Comment: @JohnBollinger for example, since IPv4 or IPv6 headers fields are 32-bit aligned, is it  guaranteed that there will be no padding?

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida, no, it is not guaranteed.  C allows implementations free reign to lay out struct representations with any amount of padding between any two consective struct members, and / or at the end of the struct.  Of course, as a practical matter, each implementation must be self-consistent in that regard, and they use padding with intention, not randomly.  If all the members are multiples of 32 bits in size then it is *less likely* that they will be laid out with padding between, but there are no guarantees.

Answer (score 2):

Hardcoding 14 is *extremely naughty*.

Why don't you use `sizeof(struct something)` instead? This is a compile-time evaluable constant expression so there is no runtime overhead.

Your hunch is correct: a compiler reserves the right to insert padding between structure elements, as well as at the end of the final element. (Note that the address of the first element must be the same as the address of the `struct` though.)